# При запуске jar файла не происходит запись в log файл

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, log4j

Добрый день, при запуске программы через IntelliJ IDEA запись в лог файл производится. Так же при открытом редакторе, при запуске программы через консоль. Но при закрытом IntelliJ IDEA jar файл запускается, но логи в log файл не записываются. Можно ли как-то сделать чтоб при запуске jar файла производилась запись в log файл? (логирование log4j)

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout,file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t]:%m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/Diplom/src/main/resources/logs/application.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5.5p [%t] %c{1} - %m%n
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос настройки логгера

Comment: В какой момент и какой программой смотрите файл с логами?

Comment: Возможно ваш jar не видит конфигурационного файла или у него нет доступа к лог файлу.  Добавьте log4j.debug параметр к JVM мож чего интересного увидите.

Comment: запустил jar файл, программа отработала, открываю jar файл через архив, нахожу log файл и открываю его через блокнот

Comment: но при запуске jar файла через IntellJ Idea запись в лог файл идёт, значит конфигурационный файл видит?

Comment: Вы пишите не в файл в jar а конкретно в "C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/Diplom/src/main/resources/logs/application.log", в нем же и смотрите.